# Prove that the composition of continuous functions is continuous using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

**Definition of Continuity**: A function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $c \in A$ if, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|x - c| < \delta$ (and $x \in A$) it follows that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.

**Theorem to be Proved**: Given $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, assume that the range $f(A) = \{f(x):x \in A\}$ is contained in the domain $B$ so that the composition $g \circ f(x) = g(f(x))$ is defined on $A$. If $f$ is continuous at $c \in A$, and if $g$ is continuous at $f(c) \in B$, then $g \circ f$ is continuous at $c$.

**My Proof Attempt**: Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Then there exists a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_1$ implies $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ (for $x \in A$).

There also exists a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $|b-f(c)|<\delta_2$ implies $|g(b) - g(f(c))| < \epsilon$ (for $b \in B$).

Let $\delta = min\{\epsilon, \delta_1, \delta_2\}$. Then, for all $b \in B$ contained in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $f(c)$ which are in the range $f(A)$, we have $$|b-f(c)| = |f(x)-f(c)| < \delta \leq \delta_2$$ $$\Rightarrow |g(f(x))-g(f(c))| < \epsilon. $$
So, given an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, we found a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-c| < \delta$ implies $|g(f(x)) - g(f(c))| < \epsilon$. Thus, the composition $g \circ f$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: The last part with the $b$ in an $\epsilon$-neigborhood of $f(c)$ and in the range $f(A)$ is not good, it is not clear. Given $\epsilon>0,$ find $\delta_1>0$ such that $|y-g(f(c))|<\epsilon$ whenever $|y-f(c)|< \delta_1$. Now for this $\delta_1$ find a $delta_2>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\delta_1$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta_2.$ This $\delta=\delta_2$ works with the given $\epsilon$ to show continuity of $g\circ f$ at $c.$

Comment: Please, don’t forget to mark the right answer so other readers will not confuse.

Comment: duplicate question.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241101/a-formal-epsilon-delta-proof-for-the-continuity-law-for-composition?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

No.  Your last paragraph just doesn't make any sense.

You say $|b-f(c)| = |f(x)-f(c)|$.  Why?  $f(x) \ne b$ (although $f(x)$ is close to $b$) so why would $|f(x)-f(x)|=|b-f(c)|$.  And you say $|f(x)-f(c)|< \delta$.  Why? You do have $|x-c|< \delta_1$so that means $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon$ but that doesn't have anything to do with $|f(x)-f(x)|$ being more or less than **delta**.

Here's a hint.  Labels are just labels.  And as $f$ and $g$ being continuous means for *any* $\epsilon> 0$ there is a $\gamma$ so that $|y-c|< \gamma$ implies $|g(y)-g(c)| < \epsilon$.  And for any $\zeta > 0$ there is a $\delta$ so that $|x-b|< \delta \implies |f(x)-f(b)| < \zeta$.

Does that look weird?  Why? All I did was change the labels.

Can you take it from there?

Hint:

> Use $\epsilon$ to define $\gamma$ as above.  Set $\zeta = \gamma$.  Use $\zeta$ to find $\delta$ as above.  Then if $|x-b|< \delta$... what happens(!)

Comment: Yeah, I'm still a bit fuzzy on my last paragraph. My intention was that, since there exists a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_1$ implies $f(x)$ is in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $f(c)$, then if we only look at the $b \in B$ in this neighborhood which are in the range $f(A)$, we know that each of these $bs$ is equal to $f(x)$ for some $x \in A$.

Comment: In regards to $|f(x) - f(c)| < \delta$, yes it is clearer to me now that this doesn't follow from choosing $\delta = min\{\epsilon, \delta_1, \delta_2\}$.